# How to get UIView by a CGRect?

Tags: ios, uiview, subview

I have UIScrollView with alot of views.
I want to identify a view by rect.
How to do it?

Tnx

Answer (score 2):

```
for (UIView *subview in [scrollView subviews]) {
  if (subview.frame == aFrame) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```